# status bar scrolling with recycle view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar

Hello I am running into a weird issue were my status bar scrolls up when i scroll my recycle view. Everything else works as it should be. I believe is the way my layout are added but I am not sure where the issue could be. If you have any ideas please let me know. Thank you!

CODE:

app_bar_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.application.app.Activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.application.app.Activity.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frame">

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try to remove `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` from the `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @vpaliyX thank you yes i tried doing this as well but no luck could it be that its in a fragment? instead of the actual activity?

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar       
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"        
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"            
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"            
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"        
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
```

The last line of code will let your toolbar scroll up. But you said 'status bar' so I don't know if this will help you or not. When I need to scroll up my 'status bar', I do it in Activity code. It may not work in your layout.

Comment: thank you yes it scrolls the toolbar as well but the status bar instead of staying and hiding the toolbar content it moves up as well which makes it weird